# Trying to find historical building footprints or centroids

Tags: data-request, geospatial, city, openstreetmap, buildings

I'm currently doing a research project analyzing how cities evolve over time and were wondering if there were any good online databases for finding historical building footprints. I've been looking around for a while now but couldn't find what I was looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This questions is a bit vague, which country?

Comment: You center of population for major world cities over the last few centuries, right?

Answer (score 0):

Very good question. Unfortunately OpenStreetMap will be of no use here. Maybe there is are established ML techniques to extract buildings from georeferenced historical maps, like the [Dufour map](https://test.map.geo.admin.ch/?lang=en&topic=ech&layers=ch.swisstopo.zeitreihen,ch.bfs.gebaeude_wohnungs_register,ch.bav.haltestellen-oev,ch.swisstopo.swisstlm3d-wanderwege&layers_opacity=1,1,1,0.8&layers_visibility=true,false,false,false&layers_timestamp=18841231,,,&lon=6.14318&lat=46.20237&zoom=11.19000000000347) in Switzerland and others.

E.g. something like this: http://lazarus.elte.hu/avhm/proc/AVHM_proceedings_01_Drolias.pdf